# Sending click events to Google Analytics in WordPress: the easy way

Tags: jquery, javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to setup a link tracking on WordPress. There are several links to the same site, they all share the same class:

```
<a class="gaClickTrack" href="https://www.amazon.es/Heromask-HeroMask-Aprende-idiomas-jugando/dp/B06XWHZ5Q4" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Buy Now Securely On Amazon!</a>

<img class="gaClickTrack wp-image-3372 size-medium" src="https://www.edinventa.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/buy-now-300x207.png" alt="Buy Now" width="300" height="207" />
```

We are using the plugin "Per page head", which allows you to add content into the section for a specific page, like custom JS or custom HTML. This is the custom code added:

```
<script>
jQuery('.gaClickTrack').on('click', function() {
    ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'amazon-button-clicked');
});
</script>
```

Note: if we use `$` instead `JQuery`, it doesn't seem to work: the console returns an error.

We are using the Chrome extension Google Analytics Debugger, but either we don't know how to use it or it detects nothing.

I can see on `Google Analytics - Real time - General Vision`, that it detects there is someone on the page, but I don't see the click event anywhere (I guess it should appear on `Real time - Events`.

Where is our mistake??

Comment: Is the content (ie, the links) loaded regularly or via AJAX after the initial payload? Can you try `jQuery(document).ready(function(){ jQuery('.gaClickTrack')... });` (aka wrapping your current code in `.ready()`)?

Comment: You may find it easier to use Google Tag Manager to manage all the tracking. You would add just a short couple of code blocks to your site, then manage any jQuery/JS in GTM itself. It even has a preview mode so you can test whether it's working before you publish.

Comment: @kero, after wrapping it, the console returns the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined`. How can I know if the function `ga` actually exists or it's a code syntax problem? Thanks so much!

Comment: @chelder Mhm that is difficult to say. Have you looked at GTM as WebElaine suggested? Would be a much smoother solution

Comment: @WebElaine I'm using the plugin `WooCommerce Google Analytics Pro plugin`. Support just answered they don't support Google Tag Manager yet. I'm trying to get a solution to use it together with that plugin anyway.

Comment: @kero support just answered... (See my answer above)

Comment: Part of the problem may be the plugin you're using to add the JS. It may be trying to execute before jQuery is fully loaded. To just test whether this is part of the problem, you can temporarily paste your code into your theme's `footer.php` file. If the event is then captured, you'll need to: remove that code so it doesn't get overwritten next time your theme updates; create a child theme; create a `functions.php` file in your child theme; and then enqueue an inline JS that loads in the body rather than the head tag.

Comment: @WebElaine wouldn't it be easier to create something like a JQuery "hello world" to output it to Javascript console? (I don't know, just guessing)

Comment: On the other hand @kero it would be cool to be able to execute a Facebook pixel fire, so it's possible to retarget in Facebook to people who clicked on that button. Also to target in Google Adwords. Notice the button takes the user to an external page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working in my WordPress site. Remember we are using the plugin "Per page head", which allows you to add content into the section for a specific page, like custom JS or custom HTML. This is the custom code added:

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 

$('.class-name-of-the-button').click(function() {  

  ga('send', 'event', {
    eventCategory: 'Outbound Link',
    eventAction: 'click',
    eventLabel: event.target.href,
    transport: 'beacon'
  });

});

});
// ]]></script>
```

Explanation:

- We must add a `jQuery(document).ready(function($){` at the beginning
- Note: I think `// <![CDATA[` and `// ]]>` are not actually needed
- As the button takes us to an external website, we should add `eventLabel: event.target.href` as it's explained here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events
- Of course, we can change .class-name-of-the-button to and add to the button an ID like push me, so it would be `$('#mybutton999').click(function() {`
- transport: 'beacon' delays loading the external URL until it's send to Google Analytics. But it's not compatible with all internet browsers.
- Again, more information about eventCategory, eventAction, transport etc. here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Finally, notice I have seen in real time in Google Analytics (on Real time - Events) when I have pushed the button to test it.